# Resizing matplotlib figure modifies padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure

I'm trying to create a figure with some supblots.
Each of the subplots has also 2 subplots side by side.
For that I've used the snippet described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67694491).

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

subfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 2)

for outerind, subfig in enumerate(subfigs.flat):
    subfig.suptitle(f'Subfig {outerind}')
    axs = subfig.subplots(1, 2)
    for innerind, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
        ax.set_title(f'outer={outerind}, inner={innerind}', fontsize='small')
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_aspect(1 / ax.get_data_ratio())
 
plt.show()
```

[image: Squared images]

The problems is that my subplots have to be squared, and if I resize the whole figure, the gaps between them and the title increases.

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True,figsize=(10,10))

subfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 2)

for outerind, subfig in enumerate(subfigs.flat):
    subfig.suptitle(f'Subfig {outerind}')
    axs = subfig.subplots(1, 2)
    for innerind, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
        ax.set_title(f'outer={outerind}, inner={innerind}', fontsize='small')
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_aspect(1 / ax.get_data_ratio())
 
plt.show()
```

[image: Gap increased images]

So, how can I keep the aspect I want but with a greater size?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [patchworklib](https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib) module can help you achieve your purpose (I am the developer of the module).

Please refer to the following code. By changing `subplotsize` value in the code, you can quickly modify the subplot sizes.

```py
import patchworklib as pw
subfigs = [] 
pw.param["margin"] = 0.2
subplotsize = (1,1) #Please change the value to suit your purpose.

for i in range(4):
  ax1  = pw.Brick(figsize=subplotsize)
  ax1.set_xticks([])
  ax1.set_yticks([])
  ax1.set_title("ax{}_1".format(i+1))
  
  ax2  = pw.Brick(figsize=subplotsize)
  ax2.set_xticks([])
  ax2.set_yticks([])
  ax2.set_title("ax{}_2".format(i+1))
  
  ax12 = ax1|ax2
  ax12.case.set_title("Subfig-{}".format(i+1), pad=5)
  subfigs.append(ax12)

pw.param["margin"] = 0.5
subfig12 = subfigs[0]|subfigs[1]
subfig34 = subfigs[2]|subfigs[3]
fig = (subfig12/subfig34)
fig.savefig("test.pdf")
```

If `subplotsize` is `(1,1)`,

[image]

If `subplotsize` is `(3,3)`,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, unfortunatly, I can't get it working properly. The first run it displays the figure, but if I run it a second time nothing gets displayed. Also, the generated pdf is empty.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience.
I realized a mistake in the second line from the end of my code.
Now, I just modified It.